# Heroku not deploying from a different branch

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I'm trying to deploy my heroku application using a different branch from master. When I run:

```
git push heroku <mybranch>
```

Nothing happens and my application is not deployed.

Does anybody know what's going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heroku apps only use the master branch (although you can push any branches you want). If you *really* do want to deploy another branch, you have to push it into the master branch on the heroku remote:

```
git push heroku mybranch:master
```